# Bootstrap menu is open when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented into my website the Bootstrap dropdown menu and the issue is that when I load the page, then as the default statue is popped up dropdown menu. I am struggling with how to have this dropdown menu hidden when the page is loaded as default.

Here's the HTML structure:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign in</a>
<div class="login_window dropdown-menu">
  ...
</div>
```

So, when I load the page, the window is displayed. When I click somewhere, then is hidden. When I click on it, then will be displayed again. That's ok.

But I am trying to have the window have hidden when I load the page. How to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add `display:none` in default css for the class you want to hide...then in jquery do

```
$("body").click(function(){
   $('.divclass').css('display','block'); /*or $('.divclass').toggle() */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the structure of your HTML wrong.  Did you look at the example on bootstrap?  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

You need to have a clickable element (button, div, span - whatever) that's never hidden.  When you click that element it animates the visibility of a sibling or child element to show the menu items.  Try using the code from the sample and simply replace the `<li>` values with your menu items.  That should help you understand the required form.

There is no need to toggle visibility on your own.